# Phonegap build html5 to android app not sound

Tags: android, web-applications, cordova

My HTML5 have a sound function (on|off). I build it to android app. But i build it on emulator or device. My function sound not start! What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Without the logcat or code snippets to work with, I'd say it's most likely that you're using an absolute path when you should be using a relative path to the audio file, or visa versa.

In the HTML 5 portion, does your path to the audio file start with file:// ? If so, try removing that part like:

file:///assets/sounds/yoursound.mp3

would become:

/assets/sounds/yoursound.mp3